# Django, sqlite выдает разный результат при использование кавычек

Tags: django, sqlite, django-model

В Django у меня происходит импорт из Excel файла. Во время этого Django делает, такой запроc.

```
SELECT * FROM "main_calc_regions" WHERE "main_calc_regions"."region_name" = '''Белгородская область''' LIMIT 21
```

Выдается ноль строк.
Но если сделать вот этот запрос

```
SELECT * FROM "main_calc_regions" WHERE "main_calc_regions"."region_name" = 'Белгородская область' LIMIT 21
```

То появляется один результат (Этого я и ожидаю). Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

```
class Calc_regions(models.Model):
   Zone = (
       ('EUR', 'EUR'),
       ('SIB', 'SIB'),
   )
   region_id = models.IntegerField("ID Региона", primary_key=True)
   region_name = models.CharField("Название региона", max_length=100)
   region_gpcode = models.CharField("Код ГП", max_length=100)
   region_supplier = models.CharField(
       "компании-Гарантируещего поставщика", max_length=100)
   zone = models.CharField(
       "Ценовая зона", max_length=100, choices=Zone, default="EUR")

   def __str__(self):
       return self.region_name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Справочник по регионам'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Справочники по регионам'
```

Comment: очевидно, при region_name = '''Белгородская область''' орм ищет точное соответствие с ''Белгородская область'' (с кавычками в названии)

Comment: Что бы получить более подробный ответ  нужен код, который осуществляет импорт, а не только описание модели.